# How to generate Schema.json of swapi-graphql for Android project?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am working on Graphql android project, my (*Facebook, through the GraphQL GitHub organization, provides a sample schema and local database of Star Wars objects.*)**Swapi** local host is up and running for request. I am also using Apollo Android. In my Android project I need Schema.json file for the variant debug. But I don't know how to generate Schema.json file.

**1. So how to generate Schema.json file?
2. Do I need multiple Schema json file for each data type planet, person, vehicle etc in single android project or one schema file contains all the information?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to generate Schema.json file?**
    use [apollo-codegen](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/downloading-schema.html) 
        `apollo-codegen download-schema http://localhost:8080/graphql --output schema.json.
Give output file **schema.JSON**.
**Do I Need Multiple Schema json file?** No, one schema for an API.

`

Comment: Hey thanks alot..I already solved it..and you can see the answer at https://github.com/KaustubhMemane/GraphQLProject

Answer (score 0):

Solve it already, Find the answer at https://github.com/KaustubhMemane/GraphQLProject